# How do I call a controller method without changing the route from the view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I call a controller method from view without route. I just want to call a method which gives me the data that I want to show on the same page. I don't want to change the route.

**in view:**
`<%= button_to "call method", { :controller => "store", :action => "call_method"} %>`

**in controller:
`def call_method
    #some stuff
    puts '<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>'
  end`

Thanks...

Comment: *How do I call a controller method from view?* - short answer: you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're asking the wrong question, you can't make a form call a method on controller without a proper route configured, cause the form action invokes an http request which gets to rails app and being routed via the app router, if no route is set to the `call_method` rails would raise an error saying no route found for the requested url.

If you want to stay on the same page/url/route, you might consider using ajax with remote forms. but still you'll need to configure a route to the specific action.

A more dirty solution would be to make the form action e the same as current page action you are on, and add a parameter specifying you called it from the form and not via standard navigation, this  is highly not recommended, but might help u figure things out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chen.. I want to make Ajax call can I do that I am not having the form. it's a simple button onclick it should call method. How can I do that. is that routing compulsory. don't mind I am very new to rails. not sure how things works in rails.

Comment: I understand your need, you'll need to learn a it more. what you need is possbile with turbolinks, but you need to understand the core principle that web app client side call interact with server side via http request and response. every server side code needs to be triggered from http path hooked to a route.